# How can you reference a template service unit for dependency?

Tags: systemd

I have a template service, `service.A@.service`, and `service.B`.  I don't know how to reference service.A from service.B so I had to creat the dependency in service.A.  I want service.B to start when service.A starts and I want service.B to shutdown before service.A when service.A is shutdown.  Is there a way to reference service.A@.service from within service.B to create the dependency?

service.A

```
[Unit]

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/my/service
```

service.B

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=service.A@.service  # I don't know how to reference a template service
After=service.A@.service    # ..

[Service]
Environment='AUTH=user:password'
Type=onshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/my/program --start
ExecStop=/my/program --stop
```

Comment: Does [systemd: service dependency "If A is not running, B should not run"](https://serverfault.com/questions/884211/) answer your question?

Comment: This answer https://serverfault.com/a/1018472/408815 definitely got me a working solution.  I used `ExecStop` to shutdown service.B.  But this doesn't answer the question of how to reference a template service unit for a dependency.

Comment: Your focus seems to be on having a service stop when another goes down, if not I'd suggest reworking the question to better distinguish what's context and what's the actual question. Right now I can't find anything that would resemble "how to reference a template service unit for a dependency".

Comment: Agree.  I muddled the question.